# AWS - CloudFormation - Enable MFA

Tags: multi-factor

Is there a way of using cloud formation to enforce MFA on user accounts in AWS:

I have the following cloud-formation code:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09"

    "Description": "Security Cloud Formation Template",

{
  "Resources": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
      "Users" : [*],
      "Action"   : [

      ]
      }
  }
}
```

I'm not able to find an action (in the AWS list) or able to work out a way of enforcing MFA on an account.

Comment: You may have better luck by contacting AWS support or posting on an AWS forum

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you can do this.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUsersToCreateEnableResyncDeleteTheirOwnVirtualMFADevice",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
        "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:mfa/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUsersToDeactivateTheirOwnVirtualMFADevice",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:DeactivateMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:mfa/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUsersToListMFADevicesandUsersForConsole",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:ListUsers"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_delegate-permissions_examples.html#creds-policies-mfa-console